# documentation generating tools for mootools class

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'am using mootools. I want to use naturaldocs to generate documentation for my mootools scripts.but I cant access the naturaldocs official site to download the tool.
so my question is :

Can someone send me naturaldocs tool, my email is knight1986910@163.com?

or

Any substitute for natualdocs that I can download?

Comment: Does this link work for you? http://sourceforge.net/projects/naturaldocs/files/Stable%20Releases/1.51/NaturalDocs-1.51.zip/download

Comment: yes I have already downloaded it,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good success with ScriptDoc for Aptana:
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/kb/aptana-studio-editor-features/scriptdocorg

JSDoc is also very nice: http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/